# How to select a particular word between non-alphabet characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have below values in a column.

```
TOM-TOM
TOMMY
TOM 12
123_TOM
SITTOM
TOM TIM
TOM,TIN
TOP TOM TON
TOMA
ATOM
```

How to select only these rows:

```
TOM-TOM
TOM 12
123_TOM
TOM TIM
TOM,TIN
TOP TOM TON
```

but not the below rows

```
SITTOM
TOMMY
TOMA
ATOM
```

If one character before or after TOM is a non-alphabet, those rows should be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a straightforward query using `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
select t.col 
from table t
where regexp_like(t.col, '(^|[^a-zA-Z])TOM([^a-zA-Z]|$)')
```

Here's a breakdown of a regular expression used:

- `^|[^a-zA-Z]` - start of a line or non-alphabetic character;
- `TOM` - TOM;
- `([^a-zA-Z]|$)` - end of a line or non-alphabetic character.

If you want to take non-english letters into account, you can use `:alpha:` instead of `a-zA-Z`:

```
select t.col 
from t
where regexp_like(t.col, '(^|[^[:alpha:]])TOM([^[:alpha:]]|$)')
```

Try this on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/439b6/1